# How can I update the ID of an entity in mysql through DAO?

Tags: java, dao, netbeans-8

//Here's my code in my AccountDAO

```
@Override
    public void editAccount(Accounts account) throws ErrorException {

            response = FAILED;
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
            String sql = "UPDATE all_accounts SET 
                         accountID=?,accPassword=?,accStatus=?"
                         + "WHERE accountID "+ account.getAccountID();
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {    
                if(manager == null){
                       manager = (DBManager) 
                                 DBManagerImplementation.getInstance();
            }

            connection = manager.getConnection();
            pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            pStatement.setString(1, account.getPassword());
            pStatement.setString(2, account.getStatus());

            pStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in editng/adding new 
                                 employee!!"+ex.toString());

        }catch (Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("Erroorr. super error!!"+ex.toString());
        } finally{
            DataDispatcher.dispatch(resultSet, pStatement, connection);
        }
    }
```

But After compiling this was my error:

> Error in editng/adding new
>   employee!!com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '111' at line 1

Comment: You might want an `=` after `WHERE accountId`...

Comment: my bad , I just forgot, but I've also tried it but it doesn't work though.. I got the same error, so  therefore that's not probably the problem..

Answer (score 1):

This is what your query looks like

```
"UPDATE all_accounts SET 
accountID=?,accPassword=?,accStatus=?"
+ "WHERE accountID "+ account.getAccountID();
```

Couple of things that stand out

- No space before `WHERE` clause
- No assignment for the `WHERE` clause i.e.

`WHERE accountID ="+ account.getAccountID();`

Comment: thanks, the error have been solved but it does not update the ID , it has no action taken..

Answer (score 1):

In your sql you are using 3 parameters but you set only two.
It should set the id also before first parameters .Also take care with no space before where and  WHERE accountID  u need to use WHERE accountID =

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set the accountId in below query

```
   String sql = "UPDATE all_accounts SET 
                             accountID=?,accPassword=?,accStatus=?"
                             + " WHERE accountID ="+ account.getAccountID();
```

Remove `accountID` and use this query

```
  String sql = "UPDATE all_accounts SET 
                           accPassword=?,accStatus=?"
                             + " WHERE accountID ="+ account.getAccountID();
```

Comment: Thanks the error has been solved, but I want to update the accountID , the query that you gave doesn't update my accountID .